# React testing library: Test styles (specifically background image)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm building a React app with TypeScript. I do my component tests with react-testing-library.

I'm buildilng a [parallax](https://materializecss.com/parallax.html) component for my landing page.

The component is passed the image via props and sets it via JSS as a background image:

```
<div
  className={parallaxClasses}
  style={{
    backgroundImage: "url(" + image + ")",
    ...this.state
  }}
>
  {children}
</div>
```

Here is the unit test that I wrote:

```
import React from "react";
import { cleanup, render } from "react-testing-library";
import Parallax, { OwnProps } from "./Parallax";
afterEach(cleanup);

const createTestProps = (props?: object): OwnProps => ({
  children: null,
  filter: "primary",
  image: require("../../assets/images/bridge.jpg"),
  ...props
});

describe("Parallax", () => {
  const props = createTestProps();
  const { getByText } = render(<Parallax {...props} />);
  describe("rendering", () => {
    test("it renders the image", () => {
      expect(getByText(props.image)).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

But it fails saying:

```
● Parallax › rendering › it renders the image

    Unable to find an element with the text: bridge.jpg. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    <body>
      <div>
        <div
          class="Parallax-parallax-3 Parallax-primaryColor-4"
          style="background-image: url(bridge.jpg); transform: translate3d(0,0px,0);"
        />
      </div>
    </body>

      16 |   describe("rendering", () => {
      17 |     test("it renders the image", () => {
    > 18 |       expect(getByText(props.image)).toBeDefined();
         |              ^
      19 |     });
      20 |   });
      21 | });

      at getElementError (node_modules/dom-testing-library/dist/query-helpers.js:30:10)
      at getAllByText (node_modules/dom-testing-library/dist/queries.js:336:45)
      at firstResultOrNull (node_modules/dom-testing-library/dist/query-helpers.js:38:30)
      at getByText (node_modules/dom-testing-library/dist/queries.js:346:42)
      at Object.getByText (src/components/Parallax/Parallax.test.tsx:18:14)
```

How can I test that the image is being set as a background image correctly with Jest and react-testing-library?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

`getByText` won't find the image or its CSS. What it does is to look for a DOM node with the text you specified.

In your case, I would add a `data-testid` parameter to your background (`<div data-testid="background">`) and find the component using `getByTestId`.

After that you can test like this:

```
expect(getByTestId('background')).toHaveStyle(`background-image: url(${props.image})`)
```

Make sure you install [`@testing-library/jest-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/jest-dom) in order to have [`toHaveStyle`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/jest-dom#tohavestyle).

Comment: This is not working for me, I get `TypeError: expect(...).toHaveValue is not a function` even with jest-dom installed. Could it be because I'm testing a styled-component?

Comment: Got it, had to add `import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'` to the test file. Found it here https://spectrum.chat/testingjavascript/help/where-do-i-set-up-jest-dom-extend-expect~ea744f78-a306-465a-a599-4abad4bc1857

Comment: I really suggest you will make a setupTests file which import this to any jest file you use :) 
and than all of the "toHaveStyle, Content, etc...." will auto import. at any test file. 
keep the development faster and solve issues you may have when you forgot to import it.

Comment: @LuizHenriqueGuerra your error msg says: toHaveValue  The answer says toHaveStyle

Comment: @Brainmaniac either way none of the methods from the expect api were working without the import in my next comment

Comment: Install `@testing-library/jest-dom`, not `jest-dom`

Answer (score 19):

If you want to avoid adding data-testid to your component, you can use [container](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#container) from react-testing-library.

```
const {container} = render(<Parallax {...props})/>
expect(container.firstChild).toHaveStyle(`background-image: url(${props.image})`)
```

This solution makes sense for your component test, since you are testing the background-image of the root node. However, keep in mind this note from the docs:

> If you find yourself using container to query for rendered elements then you should reconsider! The other queries are designed to be more resiliant to changes that will be made to the component you're testing. Avoid using container to query for elements!

Comment: One way to avoid the problem of making the implementation-detail assumption that it's the container's first child that carries the background image might be to give the element with the background image an aria-role of an image (`role="img"`) and then use `getByRole('img')` instead of `container.firstChild`. Then the tester looks up the tree for the first element that acts as an image.

Answer (score 7):

in addition to `toHaveStyle` `JsDOM Matcher`, you can use also `style` property which is available to the current dom element

**Element DOM API**

```
expect(getByTestId('background').style.backgroundImage).toEqual(`url(${props.image})`)
```

also, you can use another jestDOM matcher

**`toHaveAttribute` Matcher**

```
expect(getByTestId('background')).toHaveAttribute('style',`background-image: url(${props.image})`)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution for testing Component css with react-testing-library. this is helpful for me it is working perfect.

```
test('Should attach background color if user
      provide color from props', () => {
render(<ProfilePic name="Any Name" color="red" data- 
 testid="profile"/>);
//or can fetch the specific element from the component 
const profile = screen.getByTestId('profile');

const profilePicElem = document.getElementsByClassName(
  profile.className,
);
const style = window.getComputedStyle(profilePicElem[0]);

//Assertion 
expect(style.backgroundColor).toBe('red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm encountering an issue with backgroundImage in my Vite React TypeScript Jest project. When I create a project using create-react-app, everything works as expected. However, when I use Vite, the following code:

```
getByTestId('background').style.backgroundImage
```

returns url(default), instead of the expected value.

I suspect I might be missing some configuration. Is there anyone here who can assist me in resolving this issue? I'm using Vite with React, TypeScript, and Jest.

Comment: @samo0ha please look into this